# regular expression to replace text value in string when using MSBuild

Tags: regex, msbuild

How do I write a regular expression to replace the $version_number$ in the following example text:

```
<td>$version_number$</td>
```

This is being used as part of MSBuild script to do a deploy (ClickOnce), I'm using the MSBuild Community Tasks, I want to do something like this:

```
<FileUpdate Files="$(LaunchFile)"
            Regex="what_goes_here"
            ReplacementText="@(NewVersionInfo)" />
```

Comment: this `(?<=<td>)\$version_number`

Comment: thanks, after escaping the characters it works,  (?&lt;=&lt;td&gt;)\$version_number\$